# What is the underlying purpose of a group by statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by

Lately I have been dealing with extremely wide queries that perform a lot of transforms on data, and I am annoyed by having to maintain wide `group by` statements. This has me wondering,

*why do they exist?*

For example

```sql
select 
    company, 
    sum(owing) as owing
from 
    receivables
group by 
    company
```

Given this statement, it seems to me that the `group by` is implied.

1. There is an aggregate function
2. There only field not part of an aggregation is `company`.

Therefore, I would expect that a query engine could determine that `company` should be the thing grouped on.

```sql
select 
    company, 
    sum(owing) as owing
from 
    receivables
```

My general assumption is always that something like this exists for a reason, I just don't understand the reason, but ... I don't understand the reason.

What is the scenario that makes the existence of `group by` necessary?

**Update**

Based on comments, a point regarding mult-table queries making it less obvious to the engine. Also, a point regarding multi-nonaggregate fields.

```sql
select 
    c.name as company, 
    t.curr as currency,
    sum(t.amt) as owing
from 
    company c 
    inner join transactions t on c.id = t.comp_id
having 
    sum(t.amt) < 0
```

This (more realistic) version of the original query uses two tables. It is still unclear to me, why the engine would not know to group on `company` and `currency` as they are the non-aggregated fields

Comment: Try "Hysterical Raisins" — aka "historical reasons".  Because that's the way SQL has always done it.  In a single-table query, your inference is valid; it isn't so obvious with multi-table queries.

Comment: Let's assume you have one company (ABC) and two currencies (EUR and USD). You write the query SELECT COMPANY,CURRENCY,SUM(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)AS TOTAL FROM YOUR_TABLE. What Currency should be displayed?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example that should address these points.

Comment: GROUP BY _clause_...

Comment: @Sergey, I'd expect an _implicit_ `GROUP BY COMPANY,CURRENCY`.

Comment: @JeffereyCave, this is an interesting. I've had the same thoughts myself.

Comment: Note also that explicit is often better than implicit. A few extra characters is often worth the cost of eliminating ambiguity

Comment: I can think about at least 2 scenarios where the group by expression won't appear (or at least have no reason to apear) in the select clause and one scenario supported by Oracle, where the group by expression is not allowed to appear in the select clause

Comment: I'm not fond of an implicit GROUP BY, it has its surprising effects.

Comment: @NickBailey while I tend to prefer explicit over implicit, my question would be "Can you give an example of the ambiguitiy?". Also, the in query that prompted the question it is 19168 characters we are talking about ... more than a few.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz are you implying you have an answer? ;)

Comment: @jarlh Do you have an example of "surprising effects"?

Comment: For the fun of it,  I'll post a detailed answer later on

Comment: One example is that you have a select query, add one item to the select clause, and suddenly get less rows returned. Might surprise many users.

Comment: *I am annoyed by having to maintain wide* - do you use a computer that doesn't have a clipboard?

Comment: To the question, just wait until you get into grouping sets, cubes and rollup..

Comment: ..or if you want to play fast and loose with letting the database implicitly decide what to return in a grouping construct you could always use MySQL :)

Comment: Ends up the only reasonable answer to your question is "it is that way because the spec says so" - we aren't here to debate opinions on the spec; if you want to see it changed you'll need to lobby/join the team that writes the spec and press for change

Comment: I generally assume specs are there for a reason. More a question of "why" are they the way they are. A lot of the "already answered" points are great.

Comment: @CaiusJard I didn't know that was a feature of MySQL, thank-you.

Comment: We can't always say "why" a spec is the way it is; it might come down to "there was a design meeting one Tuesday afternoon where it was decided that..." and chances that anyone here was in that design meeting and can speak authoritatively as to why, are slim indeed.. :)

Comment: Indeed, and beware - it's perhaps one of the features of MySQL that impresses me(perhaps others too!) least, that it allows you to write queries with no/a wonky group by that every other DB would balk at, and it runs them and gives some rather odd results (it doesn't exactly implement what you seek - it just picks some value for the non aggregated, non grouped columns. For more info Google "mysql only full group by")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from Oracle which supports nested aggregate functions

Assume that you have a cube rolling results.
The following query shows us the throws distribution.

```
select   result
        ,count(*) as count
from     cube_roll
group by result
```

| RESULT | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 23 |
| 5 | 15 |
| 6 | 16 |

The following query shows us the maximum count for the results.
Please note that `result` does not appear in the SELECT clause.

```
select   max(count(*)) as max_count
from     cube_roll
group by result
```

| MAX_COUNT |
| --- |
| 23 |

Please note that `result` cannot be added to the SELECT clause.

```
select   result        -- invalid reference
        ,max(count(*)) as max_count
from     cube_roll
group by result
```

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7b637463a8161d6a9d45d38a2f864ceb)

Comment: I'll add some more examples later on

Comment: Any other databases support this oddity, or is it just Oracle? A wider reaching example would be nice

Comment: @CaiusJard, AFAIK only Oracle. You had a great point regarding grouping sets, cube & rollup

Comment: I turfed my crappy answer.... I'd still like implied groups as an option.